# Special cases in handling of higher rank types in GHC?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, type-inference, pointfree, higher-rank-types

Consider this example from a GHCi session:

```
Prelude> :set -XRankNTypes
Prelude> let bar :: (forall a.[a]->[a]) -> [Int]; bar f = f [1,2,3]
```

This defines a funcion `bar` with rank-2 type. Hence, type inference should not be able to infer the correct type for:

```
Prelude> let foo f = bar f
```

And indeed,

```
<interactive>:7:17:
Couldn't match type `t' with `[a] -> [a]'
  `t' is a rigid type variable bound by
      the inferred type of foo :: t -> [Int] at <interactive>:7:5
In the first argument of `bar', namely `f'
In the expression: bar f
In an equation for `foo': foo f = bar f
```

Surprisingly, if we write the same in point free style it works:

```
Prelude> let baz = bar
Prelude> :t baz
baz :: (forall a. [a] -> [a]) -> [Int]
```

How is it that type inference can infer a higher rank type here? 
Can anybody confirm that this is treated specially in GHC, or point out where I err.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main problem of type inference in the presence of higher-rank types is inferring polymorphic types for lambda-bound variables. In your first example, the only correct way to type `foo` is to assign a polymorphic type to `f`. In your second example, no such thing is needed. Instead, `baz` is just a (trivial) partial application of `bar`. Merely applying a higher-rank polymorphic function, without any lambda abstractions, should always be possible without additional type annotations.

See also the appropriate section in the [GHC User's Guide](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6.3/html/users_guide/other-type-extensions.html#idp49189168) as well as various research papers.

Comment: Indeed, it looks like the typechecker is happy as long as it doesn't have to infer the type of a lambda bound variable that is passed in the place of the higher ranked argument.